# How could I get the latest blog posts for Mezzanine page?

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, mezzanine

I'm new on Mezzanine and I want to display the 8 latest posts on a custom section of the home page.

I already built the QuerySet: `BlogPost.objects.filter(publish_date__isnull=False).order_by('-publish_date')[:8]`

I've already checked `templates/blog/blog_post_list.html` but I'm not clear on how can I pass the QuerySet result to the view.

Comment: Explain better what you want to achieve please, I would be happy to help.

Comment: @raydel-miranda I want to list the lastest post in my home page, something similar to what is displayed on the blog_post_list.html template but with different HTML and without modifying  the blog_post_list.html template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer [Fetch blog entries with bootstrap custom theme and mezzanine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561071/fetch-blog-entries-with-bootstrap-custom-theme-and-mezzanine?rq=1). You can use the `blog_recent_posts` tag from blog_tags. Load the tags at the beginning:

`{% load blog_tags %}`

And where you want to iterate the recent posts:

```
<ul>
  {% blog_recent_posts as recent_posts %}
  {% for blog_post in recent_posts %}
    <li>{{ blog_post.title }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```